# Is there a commonly-used source for common OpenGL shaders?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, shader, scenekit

I am an iOS developer currently making use of SceneKit to display a COLLADA model on the screen. I am being asked to make the model look like a wireframe. It seems like I can use OpenGL shaders for this, but I have no idea how to write GLSL and had thought that something as common as a stencil/toon/edge shader would be easy to find. I haven't had much luck just Googling around unfortunately.

I am currently making use of this technique for applying shaders, but his edge shader isn't working for me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yaS_BbRY0gU

Is there a common source that game developers will acquire/purchase their shaders from?

Comment: OK -- I see one vote to close on this. Care to comment on why? Or where else I could be asking this question? It is a legitimate question. Thanks.

Comment: You're asking for an offsite resource which is indeed a close reason. In addition to that googling `opengl wireframe` brings up plenty results for me. Hint: `drawElements`/`drawArrays` takes a [*primitive* parameter](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the only thing like what you want is used by web designers/devs playing with WebGL.

http://codeflow.org/entries/2012/aug/02/easy-wireframe-display-with-barycentric-coordinates/

Comment: hi @Confused (excellent avatar btw, you need a buddy "dazed"). could i email you about a potential project?

Comment: Yeah... another great feature of SO... no way to privately communicate.

Comment: great ... what's your email address?

Comment: I'm not comfortable putting up here. Is there some other way we can find to privately communicate?

Comment: I was being sarcastic, I find it VERY annoying that there's no private communication on SO

Comment: If you want to share you email address, I'm happy to send you an email.